# Candle CNC shrink

Tags: cnc

Today I tried to use the CNC for my first PCB and the result was only 1/3 the size of the Eagle diagram I made. Where should I input the machine parameters to get a proper size PCB? The CNC is working on an Arduino Uno, and I installed the GRBL master 1.1 library on it

Comment: Is is actually 2.54 times smaller?  If so, the CNC is probably working in metric, while the Eagle PCB data is in inches.

Comment: it`s not unfortunately. I have a question in the regard of the Arduino Uno inside the CNC. What i uploaded on it is just firmware form grbl-master 1.1 ( https://github.com/gnea/grbl ) .Do I need to upload anymore information on the arduino inside the CNC(maybe the step of the motors inside the CNC)@PeterBennett